# Using git eclipse project with android-studio

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-studio

I'm working on an android app project for a client. The project is developed using eclipse and is setup in github
I'm using android-studio as I found it much more convenient than eclipse on ubuntu(eclipse seems to hang a lot on ubuntu 14.04).

First time around I can do an "Import". However on subsequent git pull, I want the code android-studio to see the changed files from the git local repo and sync the code without modifying the original folder structure.
Any Idea how to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the VCS menu you can find the Show Changes View item. First click on the package directory project panel (left side of android studio) then click on the Show Changes view. In this new window you may see the differences with the repository your app is connected to.

Then you can update the project by VCS->Update Project or CTRL+T

If this couldn't help please explain more for me.

Comment: I'm unable to find both "Show Changes" as well as "Update Project". Also please not that the original project is for eclipse. So I'm not if I'm importing the project properly or not. When I import the project, it prompts for a different directory n the files get copied there(which is something I don't want)

Comment: what is your android studio version?

Comment: Do you use a git bash client?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio project can work with the same structure used in Eclipse.

You have to set this setting in a `build.gradle` file inside your project.

Example:

```
Root
  EclipseModule
    libs
    src
    res
    AndroidManifest.xml
    build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

In your EclipseModule/build.gradle

```
android {

 .....

 sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

  .......
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    .....
}
```

In your settings.gradle

```
include ':EclipseModule'
```

Comment: I tried using the eclipse to generate the build.gradle files using "Export" option in eclipse. It generates a build.gradle similar to the one you have mentioned. However I'm still having problems settings.gradle n SDK is not recognized(even tho sdk.dir in local.properties points to the proper sdk path). Let me check it.